# Will this randomized PCA operation ever finish?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm attempting to perform whitening on a matrix with dimensions (100000,1024). I need to determine whether PCA or RandomizedPCA from sklearn.decomposition can handle a problem of this size, and if not, what the largest number of features I could use is and still finish in about 24 hours. The implementation is not parallelized.

According to [the documentation for sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), the time complexity of the PCA transformation is 'O(n ** 3) assuming n ~ n_samples ~ n_features.' But I'm unsure what that ~ notation means.

[RandomizedPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA) is supposedly more efficient, because it's an approximation, but I don't know by how much. There is nothing about it's time complexity in the documentation.

For reference, I have performed a transformation to (100000, 2) and that takes about 2 minutes. I've started transformations (PCA and RandomizedPCA) to (100000, 1024) both running for about an hour. I'd like to discover whether they will ever finish, but if I can't I'll just terminate them after 24 hours if they're still running.

Comment: ~ means approximately. This formula is almost useless in practice as often one will use RandomizedPCA with much less features than samples (or the opposite). One should have a look at the paper referenced in the doc to get the exact complexity (I am not 100% to get it out of the tip of my head).

Answer (score 4):

Through experimentation it appears randomized PCA grows linearly and finished in just over an hour for 1024 features.